# NSXMLParser foundCharacters Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address=0x0)

Tags: parsing, ios7, xcode5, nsxmlparser

I am trying to implement an rss reader into a table inside a container. I have the code of the parser in an other project and in the specific project it works fine without any error. I copied every file, 4 files exactly as they are in the other project and i copied also the view controllers into my storyboard so they are exactly the same. But when i run the code i get an error!

[here is a pic with my error.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IoAIN.png)

I don't know why is this happening. In the other project which has only two view controllers with the table view and the web view it works fine. But when i try to copy every file as it is into my other project I get this error.

This is my .m file

```
#import "APPMasterViewController.h"
#import "APPDetailViewController.h"

@interface APPMasterViewController () {
    NSXMLParser *parser;
    NSMutableArray *feeds;
    NSMutableDictionary *item;
    NSMutableString *title;
    NSMutableString *link;
    NSString *element;
}
@end

@implementation APPMasterViewController

(void)awakeFromNib {
    [super awakeFromNib];
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    feeds = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://radioevros.gr/feed/"];
    parser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url];
    [parser setDelegate:self];
    [parser setShouldResolveExternalEntities:NO];
    [parser parse];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
}

#pragma mark - Table View

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return feeds.count;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath        *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell"      forIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.textLabel.text = [[feeds objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey: @"title"];
    return cell;
}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:   (NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict {

    element = elementName;
    if ([element isEqualToString:@"item"]) {
        item    = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
        title   = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
        link    = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
    }
}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName {

    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"item"]) {
        [item setObject:title forKey:@"title"];
        [item setObject:link forKey:@"link"];
        [feeds addObject:[item copy]];
    }
}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string {

    if ([element isEqualToString:@"title"]) {
        [title appendString:string];
    } else if ([element isEqualToString:@"link"]) {
        [link appendString:string];
    }
}

- (void)parserDidEndDocument:(NSXMLParser *)parser {
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"showDetail"]) {
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
        NSString *string = [feeds[indexPath.row] objectForKey: @"link"];
        [[segue destinationViewController] setUrl:string];
    }
}

-(void) viewDidUnload{
    [element release];
    element = nil;
    [super viewDidUnload];
}

- (void)dealloc {
    [element release];
    [super dealloc];
}

@end
```

Comment: Please put the error into the question itself. SO tries to not rely on outside resources to remain up and keep their content for future readers.

Answer (score 0):

I can't say for certain since I haven't tried running your code, but you may want to try to store element using `element = [elementName copy];` instead and see if that gets rid of the exception.

My guess is that `elementName` gets deallocated after you exit the method since it is only a local parameter variable.

As a side note, it appears that you are doing manual memory management. I highly suggest that you convert your project to use ARC since it not only streamlines memory management, it is also what Apple has been recommending to use for quite a while now.